# How to size UILabel that has been rotated

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, uilabel

After rotating a `UILabel` in 3D space, it becomes truncated. I do not know why the label truncates the text after rotation, as initially, the text fits fine.

Before

[image]

After

[image]

Here is my rotation code. When commenting out the code (except `sizeToFit`), everything fits fine.

```
CALayer *layer = label.layer;
CATransform3D rotationAndPerspectiveTransform = CATransform3DIdentity;
rotationAndPerspectiveTransform.m34 = 1.0 / -500;
rotationAndPerspectiveTransform = CATransform3DRotate(rotationAndPerspectiveTransform, 45.0f * M_PI / 180.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
layer.transform = rotationAndPerspectiveTransform;

[label sizeToFit];
```

I can resize the frame of the label after calling `sizeToFit`, but I am unable to determine the correct number programatically. In the following code, I determine the width of the text and resize the label's frame, but the text is still truncated.

```
CGRect frame = label.frame;
frame.size.width = [label.text sizeWithFont:label.font].width;
label.frame = frame;
```

Comment: I'll bet it's the perspective applied to the transform that's truncating it.  Reset it when you're done transforming the layer.

Comment: @CodaFi I'm not following. Can you explain the details? Thanks.

Comment: You see how you're applying an m34 perspective shift?  Reset it when you're done transforming the layer.

Comment: @CodaFi Hmmm... that didn't do anything.

Comment: Actually, that was stupid of me to suggest, as I should have look at the angle you applied.  You're going to get truncation either way because of the way transformations affect the bounds of the object.  I wish I was better at photoshop so I could draw up an image to show you how it looks laid out in a planar fashion. Suffice to say nothing you do, save manipulating its bounds, will make a difference.

Comment: @CodaFi Ok, thanks for telling me. How should I determine the number to set the width of the label to after the transformation? As I explain above, finding the width of the text and setting the label's frame to that doesn't work.

Comment: 45 degrees implies that just about half the view is cut off, so assign a bounds (not a frame) with twice the width.

Comment: @CodaFi Great, write this as the answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the 45 degree X-axis transformation, approximately half of that label is now obscured in the negative portion of the Z-axis.  The frame of the object has effectively also been chopped in half, which forces the label to truncate its text.  If one were to increase the frame of the object, they would quickly discover that it would have no effect.  Just because the frame relative to it's superview has increased, does not mean that the bounding rectangle in the label's transformed coordinates has updated.  For that, we assign to bounds.  To fix the truncation issues, assign a bounds with just about twice the width of the current label's bounds, which forces the rendering engine to regard the "negative z-axis" portion of the label as drawable.

(Apologies for a lack of graphics, as it would have been really helpful)

Answer (score 0):

Just increase It's Frame proportionally . It should work

Comment: How can I determine the ratio by which to scale the frame?

Comment: basically when you rotate by 90 angle your height and width interchange in frame. I don't know how and what angle you're rotating it.

Comment: Scaling the frame is useless, as all it will do is push the layer further into negative z coordinates.